# Ruby on Rails - Another Flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to show some login validation errors on my Rails app.

I know I can store the errors in the flash object and dump them on the page like this:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="mFlash flash-<%= key %>" data-module="mFlash">
        <%= value %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

But I want to use that as a partial globally to my application.

The positioning of that partial isn't where I want my login validation errors to go though.

Can I create another flash-like variable that's stored between controller actions? (my auth actions happen on a separate controller to the controller that renders the page).

I don't really want to do something hacky like:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="mFlash flash-<%= key %>" data-module="mFlash">
            <%= value unless (key == 'loginerrors')  %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about creating another flash, but my suspicion would be that it would end up being even more hacky.

Why not just create two partials and filter which parts of the hash they actually deal with:

```
# _main_flash.html.erb
<% flash.except(:loginerrors).each do |key, value| %>
  ...
<% end %>

# _login_flash.html.erb
<% flash.slice(:loginerrors).each do |key, value| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```